# ImageView dentro de HBox em arquivo FXML

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, fxml

Estou tentando inserir um imagem dentro de um `HBox` através de um `ImageView` mas não estou conseguindo.

Código fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" stylesheets="@../css/botoes.css" id="BorderPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="teste.FXMLDocumentController">
    <left>
        <HBox fx:id="hbox" alignment="CENTER">
            <Button fx:id="btnIniciar" onAction="#acaoIniciar" />
            <Button fx:id="btnPausar" onAction="#acaoPausar" />
            <Button fx:id="btnParar" onAction="#acaoParar" />
            <Button fx:id="btnSubirFila" onAction="#acaoSubirFila" />
            <Button fx:id="btnDescerFila" onAction="#acaoDescerFila" />
            <Button fx:id="btnRemover" onAction="#acaoRemover" />
            <Button fx:id="btnAdicionarArquivo" onAction="#acaoAdicionarArquivo" />
            <Button fx:id="btnLinkMagnetico" onAction="#acaoLinkMagnetico" />
            <Button fx:id="btnGerarTorrent" onAction="#acaoGerarTorrent" />
        </HBox>
    </left>
    <right>
        <HBox fx:id="hbox2" alignment="CENTER">
            <ImageView fx:id="image" disable="false" fitHeight="60" fitWidth="60" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
            <TextField fx:id="txtPesquisar" />
        </HBox>
    </right>
</BorderPane>
```

Para testar, eu removi a linha onde inseria o `ImageView` no fxml e adicionei a imagem através do controlador no seguinte trecho:

```
this.image = new ImageView(new Image("/imagens/iniciar.png"));
this.image.setFitHeight(TAMANHO_IMAGEM_X);
this.image.setFitWidth(TAMANHO_IMAGEM_Y);
this.hbox2.getChildren().add(image);
```

E milagrosamente não ocorreu erro algum!

Também tentei inserir a imagem dentro do `ImageView` dentro do arquivo fxml, sem criar objeto algum no controlador:

```
<ImageView fx:id="image" disable="false" fitHeight="60" fitWidth="60" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
    <image>
        <Image url="@../imagens/iniciar.png" />
    </image>
</ImageView>
```

Mas também não deu certo.

Detalhe: nesse último teste apareceu, dentre várias outras, a seguinte linha na saída:

> ```
> Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: ImageView is not a valid type.
> ```

Os meus maiores problemas com  javaFX são como este, eu tento usar fxml e um controlador e começa a brotar erros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu código FXML falta a tag `<children></children>` dentro do HBox (No BorderPane também):

```
// Supondo que sua pasta images está dentro da pasta src
<HBox>
   <children> // Esta tag está faltando
      <ImageView fitHeight="275.0" fitWidth="603.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../images/exemplo.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
   </children>
</HBox>
```

O SceneBuilder também da a opção de usar o caminho absoluto para a imagem dessa forma:

```
<HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <ImageView fitHeight="275.0" fitWidth="603.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="file:/home/usuario/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaFXApp/src/images/exemplo.jpg" />
            // Observe o file:
         </image>
      </ImageView>
   </children>
</HBox>
```

*Testado no Kubuntu 16.04 com NetBeans 8.2, Java 1.8.0_131 e SceneBuilder 8.3.0 (17/07/2017)*

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!
Quando à observação, eu estou em um projeto na escola e foi optado pelo uso do fxml, então não tenho muito o que fazer.  
Agora, se não for incômodo, permita-me fazer mais uma pergunta: 
o que seria essa tag <children> e quando devo usá-la?

Comment: Essa tag diz que um componente é filho de outro componente, às vezes existem propriedades que são "herdadas" dos componentes pai, por exemplo quando você marca que todos os componentes filhos usem o espaço disponível. No caso acima, serve também pra indicar a quem está lendo que ImageView está dentro do HBox. Não esqueça de dar ok na resposta que mais te ajudou.

Comment: Creio que entendi.

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo!!!

Comment: Quanto ao ok da resposta, está dado, mas minha reputação é menor que 15, então ele não é contabilizado.

Comment: Esqueci de comentar que a relação pai > filho é entre Containers (AnchorPane, HBox, VBox, ...) e Controles (TextField, Button, ...). Veja como aceitar uma resposta neste post: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta

Comment: Mais uma vez obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Tente montar o fxml desta forma, utilizei o JavaFX Scene Builder 8.3.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="951.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<right>
  <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="606.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
     <children>
        <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
           <image>
              <Image url="@../Pictures/987-proteam-xx1_2015.png" />
           </image>
        </ImageView>
        <TextField prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="231.0" />
     </children>
  </HBox>
</right>
<left>
  <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="356.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
     <children>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Iniciar" />
        <Button layoutX="164.0" layoutY="198.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Pausar" />
     </children>
  </HBox>
</left>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta!